# Delphi - Differences between TNotificationCenter.PresentNotification x TTrayIcon.ShowBalloonHint

Tags: delphi

Is there any difference in using TNotificationCenter.PresentNotification and TrayIcon.ShowBalloonHint methods in displaying notifications on Windows 11?

Comment: BalloonHint exists on pre-Windows 10 platforms (at least back to Windows 7), while notifications do not. Clearly, they do not use the same API.

Answer (score 0):

- **TNotificationCenter.PresentNotification**: is platform agnostic
- **TrayIcon.ShowBalloonHint**: is Windows only

Comment: Do they both call the same OS API on Windows? Do they both have the same functionality? His answer was quite perfunctory.